# Audit log SecGroupMemberdel missing

Tags: 2016, auditing

we have a powershell script to extract data from the audit log filtering by group membership update (audit   Editing users and permissions  enable at site level)

while we have a perfect match for the SecGroupMemberAdd it seems like we are missing some SecGroupMemberDel matching the group membership: we cannot see any deletion to a member that result added but is not present anymper in the groups.
I should say that the content database was attached a couple of times from a  dev farm (differente domain) to a cert farm e production farm (the last ones on the same domain)
here an excerpt of the code used

```
$searchPattern = "*<user>$userId</user>*" 
$eventType = [Microsoft.SharePoint.SPAuditEventType]::SecGroupMemberDel
$eventType2 = [Microsoft.SharePoint.SPAuditEventType]::SecGroupMemberAdd 
$usersList = $site.RootWeb.SiteUserInfoList  

  $query = New-Object Microsoft.SharePoint.SPAuditQuery($site) 
  $query.AddEventRestriction($eventType2) 
  $query.AddEventRestriction($eventType)
  $query.SetRangeStart($startDate)
```

does anyone have any hints on what it could be wrong?

thanks

Answer (score 1):

I've finally found the culprit.
I was looking for SelectSingleNode("//userid") node, while the missing Delete events only reports SelectSingleNode("//user") (always as id).
Including also the user node catch all the events